# Gitlab-Runner Windows service: build with administrative priviledges

Tags: windows-services, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, administrator

**Problem**

- gitlab-runner in Powershell on build server finishes successfully (vb6.exe, devenv.com, msbuild.exe) if running in local terminal started with "run as administrator", whereas ending up in errors while running as Windows service configured as local administrator

**Desired Behavior**

- building projects (vb6.exe, devenv.com, msbuild.exe) with administrative privileges via gitlab-runner as Windows service on isolated build server

**Configuration**

- Windows Server 2019, Gitlab-Runner v.14.3.2 64bit, powershell mode, service running with local administrator account
- Visual Studio (VS) builds need adminstrator privileges for interopability between VB6 UI (VS VB98) and VB6/C# (VS 2019) projects. During building VS writes in Windows Registry if interopt-mode in sub-project of VS solution has been selected (administrator permissions therefore mandatory).

**Try outs**

- installed gitlab-runner as service recommended by https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html
- temporary deactivated User Account Control with no success
- adapted gitlab-ci.yml to call vb6.exe, devenv.com and msbuild.exe with Powershell command `Start-Process -Verb runAs -Wait devenv.com ...`, but ended up in errors for `devenv.com` because `Start-Process` seems to accept only applications with `*.exe` as file ending. `devenv.exe` is working but not returning/closing new terminal session by Start-Process which ends up in a hanging gitlab-ci-build-script. Additionally, terminal messages of the build script are not visible anymore because they are  running in a new terminal session created by `Start-Process`.
- Deactivating gitlab-runner service and starting via Windows auto-start-folder: running Powershell-Script: `Start-Process -FilePath D:\development\gitlab-runner\gitlab-runner -ArgumentList 'run --working-directory D:\development\gitlab-runner --config D:\development\gitlab-runner\config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog' -Verb runAs -Wait`, but configured user needs to login on every system start which is not the desired behavior of the build server.
- gitlab-runner.exe/vb6.exe/devenv.exe/msbuild.exe - right click - properties - compatibility - change settings for all users - checkbox: run as administrator for all user activated - did not change the described behavior

gitlab-ci.yml

```
stages:
  - deploy

variables:
  PLATFORM: 'x86'
  CONFIGURATION: 'Release'

myproject:
  stage: deploy
  when: manual
  tags: [deploying]
  script:
    - Start-Process MSBuild.exe -Wait -Verb runAs -Argument 'AutomatedSetupBuild.proj'
    - Start-Process devenv.com -Wait -Verb runAs -ArgumentList ".\mysolution.sln /Rebuild `"$CONFIGURATION|$PLATFORM`" /Project .\myproject\myproject.vbproj /ProjectConfig `"$CONFIGURATION|$PLATFORM`" /Log"
    - Start-Process vb6.exe -Wait -Verb runAs -ArgumentList "/make `".\vbproject.vbp`" /out `"$env:TEMP/vb6-buildoutput.log`""
```

Comment: Have you tried running the service as the builtin SYSTEM principal?

Comment: Yes, following the instructions from https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html, the build-in system account step only works, if the gitlab-runner is started from a shell with "run as administrator", but the desired behavior is to get it run as service, where currently the gitlab-runner runs in errors (during project building) because of missing administrative privileges

Comment: In the services panel in service properties -> Log On tab -- how is the service logon configured? It should be set to use the system principal (or an admin user account with appropriate permissions).

Comment: We tried both, installed as local Administrator without Log On configuration in the service tab and with, but without success. It is still only working if we start the service manually in an elevated shell with ```D:\development\gitlab-runner\gitlab-runner run --working-directory D:\development\gitlab-runner --config D:\development\gitlab-runner\config.toml --service gitlab-runner --syslog```.

Answer (score 0):

What works for me is to give the user I intend to install the runner as right to log on as a service. Go to Control Panel -> Administrative Tools -> Local Security Policy -> Security Settings -> Local Policies -> User Rights Assignment -> Log on as a service . You need to add the user you installed gitlab-runner to the list, including the local domain, and then install the runner according to https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/install/windows.html, also using the full username with domain.

Comment: Thank you very much for your support! Now the build continues until 
> error MSB6006: "lc.exe" exited with code -1
which does not occur if I build with administrative privileges. I seems to me that the build user does still not have sufficient rights when running as windows service.

Comment: Sounds like you probably got problems with a GUI application? There is probably a more thorough solution if you explore the rights, but my quick and dirty trick is to log on to the build machine using the same credentials I installed gitlab runner with.